# Sqlite group dates by day

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date

I'm trying to retrieve a list of different days from table. They are stored in integer.

```
cal.getTime().getTime()
```

> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.

What I've written

```
select strftime('%d-%m-%Y'," + date_clmn + ") from "
                + TABLE_NAME +" group by strftime('%d-%m-%Y'," + date_clmn + ")"
```

Next, I convert these values toString.
What I get:

```
24-11--471
```

And after that when I try to make query with

```
strftime('%d-%m-%Y',date_clmn)=24-11--471
```

I get nothing.

What's wrong?

Will I run in trouble with timezone using this way?

If there are some other ways make it, I'll be glad to hear you.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

```
Tried "date(" + date_clmn+ ",'unixepoch')"
now retrieved value is "1970-01-01"
```

Comment: I think comparisson would be `strftime('%d-%m-%Y',date_clmn) = '24-11--471'`. Just enclose `24-11--471` in single quotes because you need to compare two strings and apparently sqlite doesn't detect this type mismatch, even query runs perfectly but of course it doesn't retrieve any row. If it works and you agree I can submit this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are not storing a date in your table, you need to change your field. Try with this code:

```
"select strftime('%d-%m-%Y'," + date_clmn + "/1000,'unixepoch') from "
+ TABLE_NAME +" group by strftime('%d-%m-%Y'," + date_clmn + "/1000,'unixepoch')"
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm adding this because I think it could be helpful to someone. As per [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) `strftime()` returns a string date in a given format.  So in this clause:

> ```
> strftime('%d-%m-%Y',date_clmn) = 24-11--471
>     ^                               ^
>   string                         this expression returns an integer
> ```

There's a type mismatch here that SQLite doesn't detect. Even query will run perfectly (I tested it and runs without errors), but of course it won't retrieve any row.

The right comparisson would be:

```
strftime('%d-%m-%Y',date_clmn) = '24-11--471'
```

**Testing**: Here's a little piece of code to test this behavior:

```
CREATE TABLE dateTest(myDate VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO dateTest(myDate) VALUES ('2013-08-29 18:57:00');
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d',myDate) AS formatted, myDate FROM dateTest WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d') = 2013-08-29; /* this won't retrieve any row */
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d',myDate) AS formatted, myDate FROM dateTest WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-08-29'; /* this will retrieve '2013-08-29 | '2013-08-29 18:57:00' */
```

And here's the output:

[image]